# javascript image resize and preview multiple function call

Tags: javascript, image, file-upload

Guys i am implementing an upload with resized image preview. the script is working, but the resize function is called many times for each img that i upload... why is this happening?

the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/LL4Dj/

and here's my code:

```
<form action="action" method="method">
    <input type="file" id="uploads" name="img[]" multiple />
    <button class="button">Enviar</button>
</form>
<div id="preview"></div>
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function imageResize(e) {
        console.log('TIMES');
        var MAXWidthHeight = 100;
        var r = MAXWidthHeight / Math.max(this.width, this.height),
                w = Math.round(this.width * r),
                h = Math.round(this.height * r),
                c = document.createElement('canvas');
        c.width = w;
        c.height = h;
        c.getContext("2d").drawImage(this, 0, 0, w, h);
        this.src = c.toDataURL();
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.appendChild(this);
        document.getElementById('preview').appendChild(li);
    }
    function previewImages() {
        var fileList = this.files;
        var anyWindow = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        var len = (fileList.length < 4) ? fileList.length : 4;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var objectUrl = anyWindow.createObjectURL(fileList[i]);
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = imageResize;
            img.src = objectUrl;
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(fileList[i]);
        }
    }
    var inputFile = document.getElementById('uploads');
    inputFile.addEventListener('change', previewImages, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its is happening because of these two lines in your < script >,

```
var inputFile = document.getElementById('uploads');
    inputFile.addEventListener('change', previewImages, false);
```

When ever an image is selected, the "change" event will be triggered and "previewImages()" function will be called.

Comment: You can add a button which will handle previews, i.e. HTML: <input type="button" id="prev" value="Preview Image"/> and in javascript.jquery: $("#prev").click(function(){ previewImages(); });

Comment: still not working with the button =(.... its like the function is called constantly until the image is added to the DOM

Comment: I see, what exactly do you mean by resize function is called many times? do you want a single image appear to preview? despite of many images vertically arranged?